# draw a convex grid polygon with 40 sides

Tags: geometry, polygons

how do I draw a convex grid polygon with 40 sides such that it is both horizontally and vertically symmetrical and all internal angles are less than 180 and vertices lie on integer coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about this is to have the polygon centered at $(0,0)$ and to have each quadrant contain $10$ sides.  In order to have a convex polygon, the coordinates must follow some pattern where the slopes of consecutive sides either increase or decrease throughout the entire quadrant.

Below is an example of a set of coordinates that work for one quadrant:
$(0,55),(10,54),(19,52),(27,49),(34,45),(40,40),(45,34),(49,27),(52,19),(54,10),(55,0)$

Comment: thank you. now i get the idea that the distance of each point from(0,0) or radius will be same but how do I find out the vertices so that the coordinates are integers ?

Comment: The distances to the origin are not the same!  Rather, I chose $55$ on purpose since it is the sum of the first ten positive integers.  All I did was increase/decrease $x$ or $y$ by $1$ through $10$ or reversed.